# How to zoom/move into the Mandelbrot set

Tags: c, zooming, fractals, mandelbrot

I'm doing the Mandelbrot set in `c` as a school project.

This is my code:

```c
int mandelbrot(int x, int y, t_data *data)
{
    double complex  c;
    double complex  z;
    double          cx;
    double          cy;
    int             i;

    cx = map(x, 0, WIDTH, data->min, data->max);
    cy = map(y, 0, HEIGHT, data->min, data->max);
    c = cx + cy * I;
    z = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (i < data->max_iteration)
    {
        z = z * z + c;
        if (creal(z) * creal(z) + cimag(z) * cimag(z) > 4)
            break;
        i++;
    }
    
    return (get_color(i, *data));
}
```

I used the `map()` function to convert the window coordinates to the complex coordinates and I used it to get the cursor coordinates in the complex space too:

```c
double map(double value, double screen_min, double screen_max
                       , double image_min, double image_max)
{
    return ((value - screen_min ) \
            * (image_max - image_min) \
            / (screen_max - screen_min) \
            + image_min);
}
```

the `data` is a struct that has the variables I need for the mand:

```c
typedef struct mouse
{
    double          cursor_cx; // cursor x coordinates in the complex plane
    double          cursor_cy; // cursor x coordinates in the complex plane
    double          min; // the minimum edge of the mand initialized to -2
    double          max; // initialized to 2
    int             max_iteration; // initialized to 100
    mlx_t           *mlx;  // the window I guess
    mlx_image_t     *g_img; // the img I'll draw my pixels to
}   t_data;
```

My problem now is moving the Mandelbrot around and zooming in and out.

1st: I managed to zoom in and out by changing the `min` and `max`:

```c
void zoom_hook(double xdelta, double ydelta, void *param)
{
    int32_t cursor_x = get_cursor_x();
    int32_t cursor_y = get_cursor_x();

    float   step;

    step = 0.1;
    t_data *data = param;
    (void)xdelta;
    if (ydelta > 0)
    {
        data->min += step;
        data->max -= step;
    }
    else if (ydelta < 0)
    {
        data->min -= step;
        data->max += step;
    }
}
```

But when I zoom in a few times the `mand` gets inverted and starts zooming out even tho I'm zooming in,
that's because `min` is moving from -2 to 0 then if I zoom more then that from 0 to 2
and vise versa for `max`.
So I need a better way of zooming in, I'm expecting to be able to zoom in forever as long as it is within the **limits** of the computer. but right now my `mand` get's inverted before reaching that limit.

And more than that I can get the cursor x and y positions so I want to zoom in into those coordinates.

2nd: I need to move my `mand` and this is what I tried but it doesn't work It's zooming in and out but in diagonal way:

```c
void key_hook(void *param)
{
    t_data  *data;
    float   step;

    step = 0.1;
    data = param;
    if (mlx_is_key_down(data->mlx, MLX_KEY_ESCAPE))
        mlx_close_window(data->mlx);
    if (mlx_is_key_down(data->mlx, MLX_KEY_RIGHT))
        data->min -= step;
    if (mlx_is_key_down(data->mlx, MLX_KEY_LEFT))
        data->min += step;
    if (mlx_is_key_down(data->mlx, MLX_KEY_UP))
        data->max += step;
    if (mlx_is_key_down(data->mlx, MLX_KEY_DOWN))
        data->max -= step;
}
```

I'm expecting it to move to the directions right, left, up and down.

So I need some help to move and zoom my Mandelbrot set.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What values do `min` and `max` hold at start and when you get problems? If you want to move around, don't you need to adjust `min` and `max` at the same time? Also, as you only seem to have one `min` and one `max` value, what does moving left/right and up/down mean?

Comment: I already commented my struct with some values to initialize it. min will hold -2 and max hold 2. when I get the problem that's already explained. when I zoom in min and max will get close to 0 but after they reach 0 they get inverted because min was negative now it's getting bigger till it reachs 2 vice versa for max it was 2 now it's reaching -2

Comment: You could simply reduce your step according to your range. `step = 0.1; while (max-min < 2*step) step /= 10;` This scales down if the limits get close to each other.